# Exception in Tkinter when information is displayed

Tags: python, dataframe, yfinance

I'm bringing an information from yfinance using python 3.11 (I'm using tensorflow which not yet is available for version 3.12) This is the structure of my application:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_regression
import yfinance as yf
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from ta.volatility import BollingerBands
from ta.trend import SMAIndicator, MACD
from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator

from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()

class StockAnalysisApp:
```

Now self.data is an atribute assigned when obtener_datos_criptomoneda() function is executed:

```
    def obtener_datos_criptomoneda(self, activo, periodo, temporalidad):
        data_yfinance = yf.download(activo, interval=temporalidad, period=periodo)
        self.data = data_yfinance.dropna()
        #Crear carperta si no existe
        carpeta_activo = os.path.join(os.getenv('CRYPTO_PATH_DATA'), activo)
        self.crear_directorios(carpeta_activo)
        #Guardar archivo CSV
        ruta_archivo = os.path.join(carpeta_activo, f'{activo}_{temporalidad}.csv')
        self.data.to_csv(ruta_archivo, sep=';', decimal=',')
```

For this data the column 'Date' doesn't exists, The Date column is indexed within the data and can be accessed using data.index, I'm trying to show this information into a table but I'm having issues to access the date info

```
        for i in reversed(range(len(self.data))):
            self.data_table.insert("", tk.END, values=(
                   {self.data.index.iloc[i]},
                f'${self.data["Open"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Low"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["High"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Adj Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'{self.data["Volume"].iloc[i]:.2f}'
            ))
```

I'm expecting that the date can be displayed in the table created for it, here is where I created the table in the class within the **init**()

```
class StockAnalysisApp:
    def __init__(self, root, crear_ruta):

        scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(self.center_frame, orient="horizontal")
        scroll_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self.center_frame, orient="vertical")
        scroll_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        #Widgets en el marco central tabla para mostrar datos
        self.data_table = ttk.Treeview(self.center_frame, columns=["Date", "Open","High", "Low","Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"], show="headings")
        self.data_table.heading("Date", text="Date")
        for col in ("Open","High", "Low","Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"):
            self.data_table.heading(col, tex=col, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            self.data_table.column(col, anchor=tk.E) #Alineacion a la derecha

        for col in ["Date", "Open","High", "Low","Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"]:
            self.data_table.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            self.data_table.column(col, anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)#Ajustar el ancho de cada columna para que se ajuste a la ventana
        #Configurar barras de desplazamiento
        scroll_x.config(command=self.data_table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.data_table.yview)

        self.data_table.config(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

        self.data_table.pack(pady=20, padx=20, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of what's in the `self.data`? It would help us to understand

Comment: no reproducible example, data is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a bad access to the information in the for loop I just need to access the date this way

```
        for i in reversed(range(len(self.data))):
            self.data_table.insert("", tk.END, values=(
                   datetime.strftime(self.data.index[i],'%Y/%m/%d'),
                f'${self.data["Open"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Low"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["High"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'${self.data["Adj Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
                f'{self.data["Volume"].iloc[i]:.2f}'
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the date information is in the index of your dataframe I mean data.index you can access it directly. Can you try this one:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(self.data))):
date_str = self.data.index[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
self.data_table.insert("", tk.END, values=(
    date_str,
    f'${self.data["Open"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
    f'${self.data["Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
    f'${self.data["Low"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
    f'${self.data["High"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
    f'${self.data["Adj Close"].iloc[i]:.2f}',
    f'{self.data["Volume"].iloc[i]:.2f}'
))
```